# json output data in specified format in excel or csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm extracting each user's data into `m4-$u.json` file with the below shell script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

USERID=ricardo.sanchez
PASSWORD=password
PORT=2728

for u in `cat user-list.txt`;
   do echo $u; 
   curl --user $USERID:$PASSWORD http://198.98.99.12:46567/$PORT/protects/$u | jq '.' > m4-$u.json
done
```

One for the user's output `m4-daniel.json` file. From that few lines as follows.

```
[
  {
    "depotFile": "//ABND/JJEB/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "16",
    "perm": "open",
    "user": "5G_USER_GROUP"
  },
  {
    "depotFile": "//LIB/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "19",
    "perm": "write",
    "user": "6G_USER_GROUP"
  },
  {
    "depotFile": "//AND/RIO/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "20",
    "perm": "write",
    "user": "AND_USER_GROUP"
  },
```

Now from the json output files, I need covert to get it in `excel (or) csv` in below format. Additionally `$PORT` & `$U` shell variables need to be present in the `excel (or) csv` file. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below (a csv file is generated). Note that there is no $PORT and $U in the data.

```
data = [
    {
        "depotFile": "//ABND/JJEB/...",
        "host": "*",
        "isgroup": "",
        "line": "16",
        "perm": "open",
        "user": "5G_USER_GROUP"
    },
    {
        "depotFile": "//LIB/...",
        "host": "*",
        "isgroup": "",
        "line": "19",
        "perm": "write",
        "user": "6G_USER_GROUP"
    },
    {
        "depotFile": "//AND/RIO/...",
        "host": "*",
        "isgroup": "",
        "line": "20",
        "perm": "write",
        "user": "AND_USER_GROUP"
    }
]
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    headers = list(data[0].keys())
    f.write(','.join(headers) + '\n')
    for entry in data:
        tmp = []
        for field in headers:
            tmp.append(entry[field])
        f.write(','.join(tmp) + '\n')
```

out.csv

```
depotFile,host,isgroup,line,perm,user
//ABND/JJEB/...,*,,16,open,5G_USER_GROUP
//LIB/...,*,,19,write,6G_USER_GROUP
//AND/RIO/...,*,,20,write,AND_USER_GROUP
```

Comment: Did you try to run my code "as is" and got this error? Dont call the file `csv` - it is a module in python. Call it `json_to_csv.py`. You need to modify the code and load the json created by the shell script into `data`.

Comment: see how you load a json file into a list of dicts. see https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json

Comment: added below whereas no repose, could you please help me with this. `import json`
`import pandas as pd`
`with open('*.json') as json_file:`
 ` data = json.load(json_file)`
`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: no need for pandas. just load the file into a list of dicts. see the example in the link

Comment: Now instead of output in `txt` changed to `json` ok will try with the link.

Comment: The file extension is not important. How ever it makes sense to replace 'txt' with 'json'.

Comment: Ok, On-top of your code as per link added `import json`
`with open('*.json') as f:`
  `data = json.load(f)` however no response.

Comment: what is the value of '*.json' - it should point to the file that was created by the shell script.

Comment: shell script created many `json` files. i mean for each user it has created one json file.

Comment: ok - lest start by one. assume you have a file named 'x.json'. Try the code now

Comment: ok `with open('m4-daniel.json') as f:` no response.

Comment: is there a file on the disk (same folder as the py script) named 'm4-daniel.json'? Are you sure a csv was not generated?

Comment: Inside `~/json-reports/` folder i have few `.json` files and `csv-report.py` script, script generated `out.csv` but doesn't have data inside. it shows 0KB.

Comment: I have installed python 3.6 and in this it is working.

Comment: it means you failed to load the json... moving to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235649/discussion-between-balderman-and-kishore).